# Регулярка PowerShell

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

Есть строка в PowerShell с вот таким значением:

```
Admins: Antonl_Sokolovskii@gmail.com, Antonl_Sokolovskii@gmail.com
Contacts: Mikhail_Alaev@gmail.com, Anton_Sokolovskii@gmail.com
Draft: False
Modified: 11/10/2015 14:23:06
Notes: Test
Multi-line
value
Project: Project-1
```

Как в PowerShell ISE получить переменную с контактами? (Contacts:) с помощью какой регулярки?

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```
$Text = @"
Admins: Antonl_Sokolovskii@gmail.com, Antonl_Sokolovskii@gmail.com
Contacts: Mikhail_Alaev@gmail.com, Anton_Sokolovskii@gmail.com
Draft: False
Modified: 11/10/2015 14:23:06
Notes: Test
Multi-line
value
Project: Project-1
"@
[Void]($Text -match 'Contacts:+.*')
[Array]$Contacts = (($Matches.Values -replace 'Contacts:') -split ',') | % {$_.Trim()}
```

Вывод:

PS C:\> $Contacts

```
Mikhail_Alaev@gmail.com
Anton_Sokolovskii@gmail.com
```

PS C:\> $Contacts.GetType()

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:Contacts:)([a-zA-Z0-9_@., ]{1,})(?:Draft:)
```

Наверное так

Comment: Не  выходит что-то(

Comment: Ну да, у меня было без учета переноса строк к первой версии сообщения. Теперь что-то типа такого. + нужен модификатор /i

```
(?<=Contacts:)[a-zA-Z0-9_@., ]{1,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, с помощью паттерна

> 'Contacts:\b(.*)\n'